# How to delete columns with all zero on every rows then sort the selected columns by its sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""probe,genes,sample1,sample2,sample3
1415777_at,Pnliprp1,20,0,11
1415805_at,Clps,17,0,55
1415884_at,Cela3b,47,0,100"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
df
```

It looks like this:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
        probe     genes  sample1  sample2  sample3
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1       20        0       11
1  1415805_at      Clps       17        0       55
2  1415884_at    Cela3b       47        0      100
```

What I want to do is:

1. Delete columns where all values is zero
2. Sort `sample123` by it's sum, descending.

The desired output is

```
        probe     genes   sample3  sample1
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1       11   20
1  1415805_at      Clps       55   17
2  1415884_at    Cela3b      100   47
```

Note here, what I want to sort is the column. So sample3 should be a head of sample1

I'm stuck at this code:

```
# Deleting all zeros columns
df[df.columns[(df.columns !=0).all()]]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, (df !=0).all()]

s = df.iloc[:, 2:].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
print s
sample3    166
sample1     84
dtype: int64

print s.index.tolist()
['sample3', 'sample1']

cols = df.columns[:2].tolist() 
       + df.iloc[:, 2:].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index.tolist() 
print cols
['probe', 'genes', 'sample3', 'sample1']

print df.reindex_axis(labels=cols , axis=1)
        probe     genes  sample3  sample1
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1       11       20
1  1415805_at      Clps       55       17
2  1415884_at    Cela3b      100       47
```

Or:

```
print df[cols]
        probe     genes  sample3  sample1
0  1415777_at  Pnliprp1       11       20
1  1415805_at      Clps       55       17
2  1415884_at    Cela3b      100       47
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to divide the columns according to whether they are sample columns or not, with

```
sample_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('sample')]
nonsample_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in sample_cols]
```

---

To sort the sample columns by sum, you can do

```
sorted(sample_cols, key=lambda c: df[c].sum())
```

(it's easy to sort in reverse or whatever as well.)

To remove a sample column if it is 0:

```
[c for c in sample_cols if df[c].sum() > 0]
```

You can use these to update `sample_cols` by assigning to it as needed.

---

Those are basically the building blocks you need. Once you've manipulated the columns' lists to your liking, you can do

```
df[nonsample_cols + sample_cols]
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want. I wanted to sort the column, not the row. So sample3 should be a head of sample1

Comment: And is it possible *not* to use hardcoded summing `df.sample1 + df.sample2 + df.sample3`. Because in reality it's more than just 3. but always 2nd columns onward.

Comment: @neversaint See update. I think it's a bit fragile to rely on column positions, BTW, so see the suggested alternative.